# Converting unicode fields into texts

Tags: python, unicode, ogr

I have a shapefile (.shp) with field names wriiten in Japanese language. I wanted to read the field names in Japanese language using the program below:

```
import ogr
infile = r"E:\shp\test.shp"
ds = ogr.Open(infile,0); slayer = ds.GetLayer(0)
fieldNames = [slayer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldDefn(i).GetName() for i in range(0,slayer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldCount())]

for x in fieldNames:
    print x
```

But, it printed out as follows, which is not readable.

```
ﾂwﾍW
ﾂxﾍW
’c’n–¼
```

How can I get readabe Japanese text for the field names?

I also tried as `x.decode('utf8')`, but got error message `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte`

How to do it guys?

Comment: `print type(x)` gives `string` though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not positive here, just trying to help, but maybe try casting the string as a unicode sequence like so?

```
a = "Hello, World!"
u = unicode(a,'utf-8')

print type(a)
print a
print type(u)
print u
```

output:

```
<type 'str'>
Hello!
<type 'unicode'>
Hello!
```

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 3: invalid start byte` using `print unicode(x,'utf-8')`

Comment: Try other encodings maybe other than utf8. try ISO-8859-1

Comment: output changed, but not yet correct. what are other decodings?

Comment: Just did a google search and this looks promising:https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html I'd obviously check out the Japanese specific encodings